# How to return a promise when out of scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to retrieve multiple files asynchronously from AWS S3 so I am using Promises.

I am using AWS S3 to retrieve the files. However, fulfill is out of scope. I am getting the following error;

```
ReferenceError: reject is not defined
```

What would be the correct way to return a Promise in this circumstance and how would it be best to provide a key to `files` with the data returned from S3?

```
var getFiles = function getFiles(files) {

    return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
        var params = {
            Bucket: 'my-bucket',
            Key: file.key
        }

        s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else {
                // set key.data = data
                fulfill(data);
            }
        });
    }));
}


var fileNames = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg'];

var files = fileNames.map(function(fileName) {
    return {
        key: fileName,
    }
});

getFiles(files);
```

Comment: should be `return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => s3.getObject(...etc`

Comment: Thank you @georg. What would be the best way to return the data from s3 and assign it to `file.key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.all` expects an array of promises. Right now your callback inside the map function is not returning a promise. You can fix this by updating the code to the following:

```
var getFiles = function getFiles(files) {
    return Promise.all(files.map(function (file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var params = {
                Bucket: 'app-design.aiir.net',
                Key: file.key
            };

            s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else {
                    // set key.data = data
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }));
};


var fileNames = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg'];

var files = fileNames.map(function (fileName) {
    return {
        key: fileName,
    }
});
```

Comment: What would be the best way to return the data from s3 and assign it to `file.data`?